# Поиск всех мест в проекте по определенной подсказке resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Есть ли возможность через resharper, в проекте visual studio (c#), найти все места, где высвечивается определенная подсказка? Например я хочу найти места в проекте, где resharper предупреждает о "possible enumeration of ienumerable".

Comment: Окно Output смотрели?

Comment: в решарпере есть инспекции. Extensions -> Resharper -> Inspections -> Code issues in solution

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Еще как вариант. Кликаем на одно из вхождений нужной нам подсказки в проекте -> Inspection "строка с предупреждением" -> find similar issues in file